# Are special rules required for ip6tables?

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, ipv6

After setting up my rules with iptables and checking that everything works, I also set up the same rules for the IPv6 addresses and noticed that I cannot connect to any of my server's IPv6 address and port. The default policy is to `DROP` everything except the ports I allow manually.

The rules looks like:

```
-P INPUT DROP
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
...
```

To be honest, I ran those commands with `iptables` and `ip6tables` and while everything works fine with IPv4, I cannot connect via IPv6 from outside.

Am I supposed to allow additional things for IPv6 that IPv4 does not require?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IPv4 used a separate protocol for finding the MAC address belonging to an IPv4 address: ARP. Because it's a separate protocol iptables doesn't affect it.

IPv6 integrated that functionality and doesn't need/use ARP. The function is implemented using ICMPv6 messages. The difference is that ICMPv6 **is** affected by ip6tables. If you don't allow the right ICMPv6 messages through you're effectively blocking yourself from using the network. You won't be able to find other systems on your LAN (like the default gateway), and others won't find you.

At a minimum you need to accept neighbour solicitation and neighbour advertisement messages. If you use router advertisements to fund the default gateway and/or use address auto-configuration you'll need to accept those as well. And pinging your machine for debugging can be useful as well, so maybe you want to accept the echo-request messages as well.

For a full list of possible ICMPv6 messages see https://www.iana.org/assignments/icmpv6-parameters.

Comment: You might want to start with allowing all ICMPv6 messages, and then narrow it down when you have a working setup. I'm personally not very worried about ICMPv6 messages, so on some servers I don't filter them at all.

Comment: echo-request messages are very useful for debugging, but they are used for other purposes as well, so blocking them can cause things to break. And of course one also has to allow too big error messages, and it might be a good idea to allow all the other error messages as well.

Comment: Those error messages should all be covered already by the ctstate RELATED rule.